# Fastest way to update the version number in Maven of all projects and modules in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently running a project in my `pom.xml` of version `9.5.0`. I am planning to change them all to `9.7.0`.

Rather than changing them one by one,I've looked into another way of using the command:

```
mvn versions:set versions:commit -DnewVersion=xxx
```

However, I can't run this command in my terminal bash since it's not recognized. Is there other way to update them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to bump the same version in multiple poms at once in my project, I always use the "replace in path" action.

Tip: you can use the `Help -> Keymap Reference` menu to quickly find the shortcut or use the `Find Action` action and type "replace in path".

[image: replace in path]

Just be careful you don't replace any unwanted versions of a dependency that has the same version by coincidence.
In the "replace in path" window you can select "open in find window" and select there which occurrences you wish to include/exclude from the replace action.